# Google adsense ads.txt status cannot be not found

Tags: angular, ads, adsense, http-status-code-304, app-ads.txt

I am trying to get my Angular website approved for Google Adsense. For this, I used an ads.txt file which I have placed in the src folder inside our Angular app e.g. src/ads.txt. However, after few days the Google Adsense website is showing  that the ads.txt is not found:

[image: google ads.txt not found]

When i tried to access the file a second time, the304  status is not modified:

[image: status 304 not found]

What could be causing this?

Comment: you have [too many redirects](https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/7679060?hl=en#root_domain)

Answer (score 1):

You should include this file into assets to make it being copied to **/dist** folder at the build time. Look into **angular.json** at the root of your project, by the path:

```
projects -> <app_name> -> architect -> build -> options -> assets
```